# REPLACE function suppresses parallelism

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, parallel-processing

Currently i am fighting a performance problem with an interesting behaviour.

I've a quite complex SQL statement (85 LEFT-Joins, 14 INNER-Joins, several subselects), with which i select about 180 columns. Some of those columns can include semicolons. As i further have to write the data as a semicolon-separated CSV file, i have to replace those semicolons.
I am doing a simple REPLACE(Column1, ';', ',') on a bunch of columns.

Now the problem: 
Without those REPLACE functions, the query is running smooth in about 30 seconds, selecting 1500 rows. Execution Plan shows me parallelism.
[image: GoodExecPlan]
The whole execution plan (just to imagine):
[image]

But, whenever i add the REPLACE functions, there is no parallelism anymore and the query runs forever. (killed it after an hour or so).
The estimated execution plan looks completely different with tons of nested loops.
[image]
The whole execution plan (just to imagine):
[image]

Is there any explanation of this behaviour? 
Why doesn't the optimizer realize, that he can do parallelism like before and do the REPLACE at the end, after selecting the data?

I tried to pack the whole select (without the replaces) in a subselect and doing the REPLACE in the outer select. But its still doesn't parallelize.
Like:

```
SELECT A.col1
      ,REPLACE(A.col2,';', ',')
      ,REPLACE(A.col3,';', ',')
      ,A.col4
    FROM (  my complex query without the replace functions here
         ) A
```

Any hints & ideas welcome.

Currently i am thinking of removing the REPLACE of the SQL statement and doing the REPLACE in my SSIS package bevore writing the data to file.

Comment: Is the REPLACE the last thing you do? What happens if you take your 1500 rows query, add a DISTINCT to it and wrap it all in an outer select that does the replace?

Comment: @CaiusJard i don't get it why i should do a DISTINCT? but i already tried to warp it in another select which is doing a replace. added this information to the question too.

Comment: Can your CSV have quote wrapped text?

Comment: You're not filtering against the replaced expression, are you? `WHERE REPLACE(A.col2,';', ',') = 'bar'` because I could see that breaking parallelism. That said, I'd just add an script component as transform (or a derived column component per replace) as this allows the ssis engine to parallelize the work. See http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/01/12/investigation-can-different-combinations-of-components-effect-dataflow-performance.aspx and the SQLCAT article that is pdf only because they were dumb

Comment: DISTINCT is something like a grouping operation; in oracle (where most of my experience lies) it will stop the optimiser rewriting the query outside the distinct into the query inside the distinct. Without some grouping op, the optimizer may look at your outer query wrapping your inner query and think it can merge them, or even move some predicates closer to the innermost query; your wrap attempt was probably defeated by the optimizer hence why it made no difference. Note: I don't guarantee that SQLServer will behave like Oracle, but I'm keen to know what happens if you *try* it!

Comment: What happens if you use the SELECT without REPLACE to populate a temp table or table variable, and then do a simple SELECT with REPLACE from that in your final query?   Obviously this becomes a two-step SELECT so you should probably put it in a stored procedure.

Comment: @KeithL: would be possible. but then i would have to replace the quotes, as those columns might contain those characters

Comment: @billinkc thx, i will check out the blog. and no, i don't use those replace expressions in the where clause. they are just plain in the select statement (those columns contain descriptions)

Comment: @CaiusJard thx for this hint. i will give it a try tomorrow, when i am back at work.

Comment: @TabAlleman interesting idea. i will give it a try. i can't put it in a stored procedure, as i don't have the rights to create them in the SQL Server where i am reading from.

Comment: @esteban. Ssis flat file destination allows you to quote wrap text. It will do it right even if there are delimiters or quotes in the column. Also, this will make it so you are not altering the source.

Comment: Scary-looking query plan... I feel your pain. I've read something from Adam mechanic where he forced parallelism and a quick Google search got me back to the article: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2013/07/11/next-level-parallel-plan-porcing.aspx. I've never tried this on my own, though this sounds like what the dr ordered.

Comment: Careful with the Distinct.  It is a sorting operator and will require SQL Server to compare every column of every row with every row.  That will add a lot of overhead.  It will also (obviously) eliminate rows.  I'd give the temp table that @TabAlleman suggested a try.

Comment: Something else you can try is applying the Replace to a few columns at a time.  This may tell you if it is a specific column (i.e. varchar(max)) or if it is just the quantity of function calls that is slowing things down.  If you're not filtering on the replaced columns, I bet you've got some (max) columns that are to blame.

Comment: @WesH: yep, already tried that. but its suppressing the parallelism if i just add one REPLACE. there is no varchar(max). all of them are a maximum of varchar(255)